# Expose C++ member function that has std::function as argument with boost::python

Tags: python, c++, c++11, boost, boost-python

I have a class that contains an attribute which is a std::function. I set the value of this attribute using a member function, so the class looks like this:

```
class ClassName
{    
public:
    void SetCallbackFunction(std::function<void (int i)> callbackFun) {
        m_callbackFunction = callbackFun;
    }

protected:
    std::function<void (int i)> m_callbackFunction;
};
```

I need to expose this class to Python and, of course, I need to expose the `SetCallbackFunction` function. 
How can I do this with boost::python?

Comment: You should add the tag [tag:boost-python] in order to maximize the chances of your question reaching an expert in the library. ([tag:boost]+[tag:python]!=[tag:boost-python]).

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I've added the boost-python tag

Answer (score 7):

As Python objects are both Callable and CopyConstructible, the simplest approach is to expose an auxiliary function as `SetCallbackFunction` that accepts a `boost::python::object`, then delegates to the actual `SetCallbackFunction` function:

```cpp
void ClassName_SetCallbackFunction_aux(ClassName& self, boost::python::object object)
{
  self.SetCallbackFunction(object);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<ClassName>("ClassName", python::init<>())
    .def("set_callback", &ClassName_SetCallbackFunction_aux)
    // ...
    ;
}
```

When `ClassName::SetCallbackFunction` is directly exposed to Python and invoked,  Boost.Python will search its registry at runtime to locate a from-Python converter for `std::function<void (int)>`.  As this conversion has not been explicitly registered, Boost.Python will fail to dispatch the function call.  The auxiliary function avoids this runtime conversion check and constructs a `std::function<void (int)>` object from a `boost::python::object`, as the `boost::python::object` is both Callable and CopyConstructible.

---

Here is an example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14bbf46502bdb746) using an auxiliary function to assign Python objects as callbacks:

```cpp
#include <functional> // std::function
#include <boost/python.hpp>

// Legacy API.
class spam
{
public:
  void SetCallbackFunction(std::function<void (int)> callback)
  {
    callback_ = callback;
  }

  void perform(int x)
  {
    callback_(x);
  }

private:
  std::function<void (int)> callback_;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  // Expose spam.
  python::class_<spam>("Spam", python::init<>())
    // Use an auxiliary function to set Python callbacks.
    .def("set_callback", +[](spam& self, boost::python::object object) {
      self.SetCallbackFunction(object);
    })
    .def("perform", &spam::perform)
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> called = False
>>> def perform_x(x):
...     assert(42 == x)
...     global called
...     called = True
... 
>>> spam = example.Spam()
>>> spam.set_callback(perform_x)
>>> assert(not called)
>>> spam.perform(42)
>>> assert(called) # Verify callback was invoked
>>> spam.set_callback(lambda: None)
>>> try:
...     spam.perform(42)
...     assert(False) # Verify callback fails (the lambda accepts no args)
... except TypeError:
...     pass
...
```